# LINQ to SQL - Insert New Record

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a database table with an auto-incrementing ID field. this table is exposed to by code via a Entity Data Model. I am trying to write a new record to this table. I have a method that needs to be responsible for creating these records. This method takes in the property values of the record. It needs to create a record, and write a reference record in another table. Currently, here is what I am trying

```
public int CreateRecord(string name, string description, List<int> ids)
{
  using (DatabaseContext database = new DatabaseContext())
  {
    Record record = new Record();
    record.Name = name;
    record.Description = description;

    database.Records.InsertOnSubmit(record);
    database.SubmitChanges();

    List<RecordTrack> tracks = new List<RecordTrack>();
    foreach (int id in ids)
    {
      RecordTrack track = new RecordTrack();
      track.RecordID = record.ID;
      track.ID = id;
      tracks.Add(track);
    } 
    database.Tracks.InsertAllOnSubmit(tracks);
    database.SubmitChanges();
  }
}
```

I can't seem to get the record to save in this manner. I was able to do it when I passed a Record in that I wanted to insert. But due to other factors, I need a way to purely create the record here from scratch. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Not nearly as fluent in L2S as I should be (thus a comment, not an answer) but don't you need to retrieve your record from the Db Context after it's inserted?  Your reference wouldn't have updated it's ID yet, no?

Comment: Is your track table also auto-incrementing? In that case you cannot set the ID like you do here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there should be a `AddToRecord()` function in your database context.  Use that function to add your `record` variable and then call `SaveChanges()` from your database context.

Comment: I don't have a AddToRecord function. Is this an extension method associated with a namespace I'm not referencing? I googled' it and didn't see it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: It should be a function that is autogenerated by your context.  I suppose that since you have `SubmitChanges` instead of `SaveChanges`, you are using something I am not familiar with.

Comment: Try db.TableName.Add(record);  then db.SaveChanges();

Comment: I can't find the methods too! what to do?