# Save country dropdown values in SQL Server database in c#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have created a form using asp.net & c# with Country dropdown field , for this I have used bind countries code as below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<string> objcountries = new List<string>();
        CultureInfo[] objculture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);

        foreach (CultureInfo getculture in objculture)
        {
             RegionInfo objregion = new RegionInfo(getculture.LCID);

             if (!(objcountries.Contains(objregion.EnglishName)))
             {
                 objcountries.Add(objregion.EnglishName);
             }
        }

        objcountries.Sort();
        ddlCountries.DataSource = objcountries;
        ddlCountries.DataBind();
    }
}
```

but I do not understand how to store the selected value in the database. DO I need to create a separate table for countries? Please explain.

Comment: It's actually not very transparent what you ask. The answer that pops up right away is "no", because the scenario in which you would use this seems to apply to a broarder scope. Perhaps a user object, which would then hold the selected value from the dropdown. Am I right? Otherwise, please elaborate.

Comment: @Heki I want to store selected country value in database

Comment: That's what I don't understand. Do you want to have a copy of the list of countries from Culture-/RegionInfo in the database?

Comment: yes I want to copy the country names

Comment: Then yes, you will need a separate table in the database, unless you already have one that contains such information. I believe the benefit from this will be very small in the scope of your question. However, if you need to use the data for data filtering, it would make sense to have a copy. You can just store the values 1:1 like having a `LCID`-, an `EnglishName`-column and so on. Is this what you want?

Comment: can you tell how to do it or any reference that could help?

Comment: Well, you already have the loop. All you need to do now is run that code once and have it add the data to your table. This describes how to add data with LINQ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112825/linq-to-sql-insert-new-record